# Twitter Bootstrap Auto Resize Picture to take up entire column

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I have a row with two columns. One of the columns has one picture in it which should take up all of the space in the column. The column on the right has three rows in it with 2 pictures in each row. But so far I can't get the image on the left to resize correctly and just stays at a small fixed size. 
Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom2.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="row">
                <h2>Recent</h2>

                <div id="myGallery" class="col-md-7">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/9-12,13 40.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>

                 <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6"><a href="#"><img src="images/9-12,13 40.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-md-6"><a href="#"><img src="images/9-12,13 40.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                        </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6"><a href="#"><img src="images/9-12,13 40.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-md-6"><a href="#"><img src="images/9-12,13 40.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                        </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6"><a href="#"><img src="images/9-12,13 40.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                        <div class="col-md-6"><a href="#"><img src="images/9-12,13 40.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                        </div>
                 </div>
            </div>  
        </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

and my css

```
img
{
 max-width:auto; 
 max-height:auto;   
}
```

I have been able to set a minimum width for it like

```
.myClass img{
    min-width: 775px; 
}
```

but if the browser window size changes then it stays the same size and doesn't look as good.

Here is what it currently looks like
[image: before]

And it should look like this
[image: after]

How do I go about fixing this in the css?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried `width: 100%`?

Comment: Have you tried making the image width 100% in the css?

Comment: Yes but it didn't affect it at all

Comment: Can you share an example on jsFiddle or bootply?

Comment: Nevermind the width 100% did work. I just had something in the wrong spot. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should just set the image to have a width of 100%. That make the element take 100% of the width of the container it is inside:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This is what Bootstrap's [`img-responsive`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images) class is for.

Comment: Not really, that uses `max-width` which doesn't scale images up.

Comment: @DanielApt So far, yours was the best solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Use Boostrap's [`img-responsive`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images) class.

Comment: Good answer to get a responsive behavior. That is not exactly what op needed, but it is what I needed. Thanks !

Comment: @Daniel Apt thanks! your advice helped me explaining how to center and scale image in a responsive way! thank you :-)